# Phase current measurement in a BLDCmotor using STM32

Tags: stm32, embedded, brushless-dc-motor, timer

I need to know about the AC current measurement for the BLDC motor.

I tried to measure phase current for only one phase for two commutation states. I use an STM32F103C8 controller for controlling the BLDC motor. I need some clarification on measuring phase current for the BLDC motor. I use Timer 1 to generate PWM and Timer 4 for changes that occur in the commutation state (ie step change occurs using XOR operation.) I am using the MOSFET Rdson method to measure the phase current (AC current) and ADC2 injected method for measuring the voltage drop on Rdson.

I tried to measure the phase current for only one phase (phase - B) for two commutation states (state1,state3.) Since the value I get from ADC2 is varying, I tried to make an average of that ADC2 reading. I used TIM1 interrupt for PWM generation (15KHz) and for some calculation and that include summing up, the ADC2 reading, and the average part is done in TIM4. It does isn't work. There still is a variation in the reading. Is there any method for measuring phase current that will help me to measure the current?

The MOSFET Rdson method is that when the current is passed through the MOSFET there will be a voltage drop across the source to drain. The voltage drop is amplified by an op-amp and the output is read with ADC2.

Scope image of the amplified signal:

- Channel 1 - Amplified signal (phase B MOSFET)
- Channel 2 - Current waveform on phase B

[image]

[image]

Op-amp circuit
[image]

Comment: Your images are not labelled and therefore cannot reference any circuit node (even if you had posted a circuit diagram of what and where you were measuring).

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks for your response  channel 1 - Amplified signal (Phase B MOSFET)
channel 2 - Current waveform on phase B

Comment: This isn't a forum. Fix your question and add the schematic.

Comment: @Andyaka I uploaded the schematic. Is there any method for controlling the AC current for the BLDC motor?